# Can someone identify this ant queen?

Tags: species-identification, species, ant

I know it's kind of hard to see but can anyone tell what it is?
[image]

Comment: Sorry, but this is so blurry had a hard time to find the ant at first sight. Please try to get a better picture and add information about where you found this ant, otherwise it will be unlikely someone is able to identify it.

Comment: I found this ant in my backyard in North Carolina when I get home I'll get a better pic.

Comment: How do I add another pic?

Comment: You can edit your post.

Comment: [edit] to edit.